# Angular 7 mat autocomplete with filter not working

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular7

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete mechanism but I can't make it work.
I've realized a Stackblitz with the logic I'm using (you can find it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbqt6v)), and it is working as it should.
The problem is that in my app is not working properly: if I set the focus to the input, I do not get the list of data on which I can filter the user input.
The only different thing in my code is that I get the data from server, so my `ngOnInit()` function is a bit different:

```
     ngOnInit() {
    this.networkService.getDataFromServer().subscribe(c => {
      DATA = c;
      this.cooperativeFiltrate = this.cercaCooperativa.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      )
    });
  }
```

How can I fix this behaviour?

**UPDATE**
I've checked some things, and the `_filter` function, the first time with no user input, returns the array with all the values. The if I write something it filters the values correctly. But the autocomplete still doesn't show any value.

Comment: Can you clarify the exact steps to reproduce? In your StackBlitz, if I type "test1", it only shows "test1". I can select "test1", then delete "1" of "test1" and it shows all three items. If I add a "2", and it comes "test2", it only shows "test2". If I then delete all text, it shows all options. It seems to be working as a filterable list usually would. What exactly is the issue? How to replicate it exactly? If I click away, it doesn't show any options, as the mat autocomplete works when it's not focused.

Comment: The behaviour in the stackblitz is the correct one, that is: I focus the input and the 3 options show up and if I write something the filter works correctly as you explained. In my app if I focus on the input the options do not show up, but apparently the filter works (I've tried putting some console.logs to check what's in the filtered array and it shows the results that it should - filtered or not). Anyway I've found the solution yesterday, so I'm posting it

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I have two mat-autocomplete in the same component, and Angular has some problems if all the autocompletes are not set (that is, linked to a data source). I had no clue this could happen, I've discovered it by chance by deleting the second one. This is way I didn't put it in the stackblitz, because I had no idea it could even be a problem.
I don't know if there's a known issue open on Github about this or if it's a normal behaviour.
Once I've set the filter and valuChanges function for the other autocomplete, they both worked normally.